# Javascript array fails to fill inside a loop but otherwise works. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have some json data and want to capture all of the persons in the dataset who have not paid dues. When I run this code with the commented out if statement(as shown), it prints correctly to the console and the html page, which has nothing but a id=demo in a div.
Problem: As soon as the if statement is uncommented, the console.log give correct output but the html page shows two (not 3) lines with "undefined". Why?  I am out of ideas about what else to change.

```js
var data;
data =[{
        "dues paid": "",
        "name": "john",
        "age": "18",
        "city": "Jamestown"
    },
    {
        "dues paid": "100",
        "name": "marvin",
        "age": "27",
        "city": "Dallas"
    },
       {
        "dues paid": "100",
        "name": "janice",
        "age": "22",
        "city": "Denver"
    }
 ]
let arr = [];
let checkbox = document.getElementById("check");

function setup() {
  let strLine = ""; 
  let checked = checkbox.checked;

  if(checked)
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i]['dues paid'] !== "" ){
      console.log(i,data[i]['name']);
      arr.push(data[i]['name'] );
      strLine = strLine + arr[i] + "\<br>";
    }
  }
  else
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //if (data[i]['dues paid'] !== "" ){
      console.log(i,data[i]['name']);
      arr.push(data[i]['name'] );
      strLine = strLine + arr[i] + "\<br>";
    //}
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = strLine;
}

document.getElementById("test").onclick=setup;
```

```html
With if: <input type="checkbox" id="check"/><br/>
<button id="test">Test</button>
<p>Output below</p>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: using `arr[i]` only works if you push in every iteration in that loop, as soon as you miss one push due the the condition, `arr[i]` will not work for obvious reasons - do something like `let item = data[i].name; arr.push(item); strLine = strLine + item + "\<br>";`

Comment: this line will always work: `strLine = strLine + data[i]['name'] + "\<br>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the `if` statement, the indexes in `arr` are not the same as the indexes in `data`. As soon as you filter out an element, the indexes stop matching up.  So `arr[i]` will not contain the name that you just pushed.

Put `data[i]['name']` in `strLine` rather than `arr[i]`.

```js
var data;
data =[{
        "dues paid": "",
        "name": "john",
        "age": "18",
        "city": "Jamestown"
    },
    {
        "dues paid": "100",
        "name": "marvin",
        "age": "27",
        "city": "Dallas"
    },
       {
        "dues paid": "100",
        "name": "janice",
        "age": "22",
        "city": "Denver"
    }
 ]
let arr = [];

function setup() {
  let strLine = ""; 
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i]['dues paid'] !== "" ){
      console.log(i,data[i]['name']);
      arr.push(data[i]['name'] );
      strLine = strLine + data[i]['name'] + "<br>";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = strLine;
}

setup();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: I'd make the code a little more DRY - `let item = data[i].name; console.log(i,, item); arr.push(item); strLine = strLine + item + "<br>";` - actually I'd use array filter and map :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I usually prefer to keep the structure close to the original, unless there's a good reason to change it (e.g. switching to prepared queries).

Comment: This isn't Code Review.

Comment: sure, but at least the DRY version isn't a departure from the original :p but I get it

Comment: No need to bring Code Review into your squabble. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.filter [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and Array.map [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from javascript

```
const unPaidUsers = data.filter((user) => user['dues paid'] !== '').map((user) => user.name); // ["marvin", "janice"]
```